# Which one is correct in-app-purchase product type?

Tags: in-app-purchase, app-store

1. After login, our app rendered on Home Screen Which display a video listing, where user have to pay one time for each video. (we are getting video listing from backend)
2. After successful purchase of individual video the download-button change to play-button (this part we managed at our back end).
3. at iTunes only I define one product for video download that is non-Consumable type As per apple guideline if our app sale a video content then the product-type should be non-Consumable.
   so the case is if I going to download Second Video through my App with same Product-Identifier then its shows me alert the product is already purchased due to the product is non-consumable.

we are stucked on that point.
What we should choose the Product-type to achieve that functionality.
Actually we have no idea about how many videos shows on Video Listing Page.
Is there any way add dynamically products on iTunes or Is there any way achieve that.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about a business concern related to the App Store, not a coding issue. Please see [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic for Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/175701) and [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The easiest way would probably to let people buy credits/coins/currency via in app purchases (consumable) and let them purchase the videos with it. Therefore you can add new videos in the future. The only issue would be, how to "restore purchases", as I assume your customers expected to be able to restore their video purchases on a new device etc.

The more complicated way would be to have a unique in app purchase for each video, which users can easily restore, i.e.
video-1, video-2, video-3 etc. The only "issue" is here that once you add new content, you need to also add new IAPs.